# how to structure the data in tables format?

Tags: mysql, sql, r, excel, data-manipulation

I have the following data in .dat format which i opened in excel and it turns out this way

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
7::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
```

I want to structure it in table format like below..

```
 Movie ID  Movie Name   Year of Release  MovieType1 MovieType 2 MovieType 3
   1       Toy Story           1995       Animation  Children's  Comedy
   2       Jumanji             1995       Adventure  Children's  Fantasy
   3       Grumpier Old Men    1995       Comedy     Romance
```

and so on..

should i use R  for it..or is it possible in excel itself ?

Comment: Why have you chosen the MySQL tag?  Are you aiming to import the file into MySQL?

Comment: Sure, you can use R to prepare this data.

Comment: Is my answer what you are chasing or do you wish for me to do further research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import the data into an Excel spreadsheet, please try these instructions...

1. Start Excel.
2. Choose File --> Open.
3. Choose Browse...
4. Change the File Type to "All Files (*.*)".
5. Navigate to and select your .dat file.
6. Choose the Open button.
7. Choose the delimited option if it has not defaulted to that.
8. Set the "Start import at row" to the number of the row where your
   data starts.
9. Choose "My data has headers" if appropriate.
10. Choose "Next".
11. Unselect any value in the Delimiters collection bar "Other".
12. Select "Other" if it is not already selected.
13. Enter a colon into the textbox next to "Other"
14. Select "Treat consecutive delimiters as one" if not already
     selected.
15. Choose "Next".
16. Set the column data formats as appropriate.
17. Choose "Finish".

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.